# searchView with room database

Tags: android, searchview

I am using searchView with room database to filter result of a recyclerView inside a Fragment.

When I click on any item of the recyclerView it navigates to detailsFragment using Navigation component library.

Till here everything works fine, The problem is when I pressed the back button from detailsFragment to go back to BooksFragment the recyclerView disappears.

This problem appears only when I implemented searchView functionality before it I was able to navigate forward and back without any problems.

What is wrong in my code and how to solve it.

**my Adapter**

```
public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.BookViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Book> mBookList;
private List<Book> mBookListFiltered;
private BookViewModel bookViewModel;
private Context context;

public BookAdapter(Context context, BookViewModel bookViewModel) {
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.bookViewModel = bookViewModel;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
    return new BookViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mBookList != null) {
        int  listNumber = position + 1;
        Book current    = mBookList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getBookTitle());
        holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(listNumber));

        // on item clicked
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_BookFragment_to_detailsFragment));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mBookList != null)
        return mBookList.size();
    else return 0;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> bookList) {
    mBookList = bookList;
    mBookListFiltered = bookList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                filterResults.count = mBookListFiltered.size();
                filterResults.values = mBookListFiltered;
            } else {
                String searchChr = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                List<Book> resultData = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Book book : mBookListFiltered) {
                    if (book.getBookTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchChr)) {
                        resultData.add(book);
                    }
                }
                filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                filterResults.values = resultData;
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            mBookList = (List<Book>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final AppCompatTextView title, number;
    private AppCompatImageView imgSave;

    private BookViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv__title_number);
    }
}
}
```

**Book Fragment**

```
public class BookFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentBookBinding mBinding;
private BookViewModel mBookViewModel;
private BookAdapter adapter;

public BookFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);

    mBookViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BookViewModel.class);

    adapter = new BookAdapter(getContext(), mBookViewModel);
    mBinding.recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    mBinding.recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mBookViewModel.getAllBooks().observe(this, books -> adapter.setBooks(books));

    // to make all searchView box clickable
    mBinding.searchView.setOnClickListener(v -> mBinding.searchView.setIconified(false));

    mBinding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return mBinding.getRoot();
}
}
```

Comment: You should set that if your searchview is empty, your recyclerview will be shown completely

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mBookList.addAll((List<Book>) filterResults.values);
```

instead of

```
mBookList = (List<Book>) filterResults.values;
```

if still the problem exist , you have to read about ArrayList cloning ,
ArrayList clone() method is used to create a shallow copy of the list. In the new list, only object references are copied.If we change the object state inside first arraylist, then changed object state will be reflected in cloned arraylist as well.